# How could I upload huge data from local mysql server to online database?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have a table (on localhost) having more than 158K rows and I want to upload them to my online database in internet.

I tried to upload it but failed (504 Gateway Out), then I tried to zip it to minimize the size (from 15 MB to 1.5 MB) but still same issue.

Please help me to resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 checkboxes on the page Import: `Browse your computer` and `Select from the web server upload directory /home/...` Upload your file in such directory `/home/...` and try to import again

Comment: I opened the (Import) page and searched for it, but not found it :-(

Comment: What version phpmyadmin do you use?

Comment: I think that (Select from the web server upload directory ...) is not available with me. So any other solutions?

Comment: Do you have any access except phpmyadmin? Maybe you can try import dump from console.

Comment: The version of PHP is 5.6, and MySql is 5.6, Apache/2.4

Comment: No more access except phpmyadmin, sorry :-( .

Comment: Try to open file dump with some text editor, copy several lines and perform them in phpmyadmin

Comment: Ok. In case of multiple `insert into` sql code: how much size does the sql stand in one query? I mean 'for example':

`INSERT INTO table (names) VALUES ('value'), ('value2'), ('value3'), ....`

Comment: take 5000 lines, If it doesn't work, take 2000, then 1000 and etc

Comment: Thanks so much, I owe you. ^_^

Comment: Just to add to this, you need to configure `$cfg['UploadDir']` (https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_UploadDir) in your config.inc.php before the Select from... dropdown will appear.